# Positioning images in random places

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I want to position random images in random places of the screen. I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(showLetter);
var imgsArray = ["A1", "C1", "F1", "J1", "K1", "L1", "S1", "Ñ1"];

function generateRandomForArray() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
    return num;
}

function generateRandom() {
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
    return num;
}

function showLetter() {
    var letter = imgsArray[generateRandomForArray()];
    $("div").append("<img src='imgs/" + letter + ".png'>");
    var left = generateRandom();
    var top = generateRandom();
    $("div").last().css({"top": top + "px", "left": left + "px"});
}
```

The images appear on top left of the screen. Once again: I want to position them in random places of the screen. I don't know much about CSS. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like positioning issue for me. Try like this, i.e., I added `position:absolute`

```
function showLetter() {
    var letter = imgsArray[generateRandomForArray()];
    $("div").append("<img src='GameHTML5/images/" + letter + ".png'>");
    var left = generateRandom();
    var top = generateRandom();
    $("div").last().css({"position":"absolute","top": top + "px", "left": left + "px"});
}
```

Comment: Yes! :D This worked. I had a class in CSS like this `img
{
    position:absolute;
}` I thought that it would be applied to all the images...? Anyway. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateRandomForArray(min, max) {
  var num = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  return Math.floor(num);
}

//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//3
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//0
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//2
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//4
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//5
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//7
//generateRandomForArray(0, 8);
//4
```

Comment: Hi @Tamil! Thanks for your time but I don't think you understood my problem :P

Comment: @user2484181: Accepted :P. But I am keeping my answer for folks who might come in future.