# How to get my thumbnails to display in random positions (in archive page wordpress)

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, random, position

I have registered a custom post type in my theme (no plugins) in my functions.php wordpress file like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'Works',
array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Works' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Work' )
  ),
'public' => true,
'description' => ('Work'),
'has_archive' => true,
'taxonomies' => array('category'),
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
)
);
}
```

I have then created an "archive-works.php" where I am only showing this custom post-type. And there I am merely showing the thumbnails and the title when you hover. Those thumbnails are links (there is a "a" tag around the "img"). And they are being styled like this:

```
#content img {
width: 70%;
height: auto;
}
```

Meanwhile I have wrapped a ".js-container" class around all links.

```
<div class="js-container">
<a href="http://dev.visualvisual.com/works/work-3/" title="Work 3">
    <img width="960" height="630" src="http://dev.visualvisual.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/10476558_10152767209223872_3064425635001081899_o.jpg" 
class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" 
alt="10476558_10152767209223872_3064425635001081899_o" 
srcset="http://dev.visualvisual.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/10476558_10152767209223872_3064425635001081899_o.jpg 960w, http://dev.visualvisual.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/10476558_10152767209223872_3064425635001081899_o-300x197.jpg 300w, http://dev.visualvisual.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/10476558_10152767209223872_3064425635001081899_o-768x504.jpg 768w" 
sizes="(max-width: 960px) 100vw, 960px">
</a>
</div>
```

I want the images to deviate ever so slightly from their natural positions. I mean, I need to place them randomly position-wise (more on the left or on the right, and if possible slightly above or below of where they should be.
I was doing a bit of research and I have found this example: [Positioning images in random places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358084/positioning-images-in-random-places)

I know it is a combination of javascript and css as in the example above. This is my current stage: http://dev.visualvisual.com/works/
I have tried typing this on the header.php file but with no results:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.js-container a img').each(function() { 
var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400), left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
$(this).css({
"top": top, 
"left": left, 
"position":"absolute", 
"display":"inline-block"
}); 
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me out here?
Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "place them randomly"? Position-wise or order-wise? If you need a random position, it's a combination of JavaScript (jQuery) and CSS (top, left, position: absolute) and it has almost nothing to do with the Wordpress or PHP itself.

Comment: I need to place them randomly position-wise (more on the left or on the right, and if possible slightly above or below of where they should be. I know it is a combination of javascript and css as in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358084/positioning-images-in-random-places
However I do not know the name of the images because they will be added later. Hence the php part: I believe i need to get the thumbnails dynamically and place them in an array so I can later manipulate them. Or maybe I can just get them by class name?

Comment: It is not hard to do that per-se. It's just the question of what edge cases you would like to consider. Should the elements overlap? Should it automatically reposition on windows resize? If so, should it just adjust the positions proportionally or could it completely reposition? Would you like to involve some animations while repositioning? From a technical standpoint, it's fairly easy. You need to contain the images (thumbnails) in some div, then apply a position: absolute to all img tags in that div. And then run a javascript on read and resize with top() and left() modification.

Comment: Thanks Miroslav.
to answer you questions: I don't mind them to overlap because they are draggable. the images should reposition proportionally on window resize.
but there is still the problem that I don't know the image names. I only know a class (.works – the images are loaded on the page via php).
this is the page: http://dev.visualvisual.com/works/

Comment: You don't need to know the image names, you just need an array of images, which jQuery will happily provide. As I wrote, contain the loop in a div container (with some class associated - I usually prefix the class with "js-"), then use jQuery to query the images 

`$('.js-container img').each(function() {
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400), left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  $(this).css({"top:" top, "left": left, "position": "absolute"});
});`

You will need to play with the randomisation as well to constraint it to region and it's just a pseudocode, but should help.

Comment: Btw, as I can see, you have it wrapped in "a" tag as well, so you might need to work with the anchors directly like this:

`$('.js-container a').each(function() { var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400), left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400); $(this).css({"top:" top, "left": left, "position": "absolute", "display": "inline-block"}); });`

Comment: I have done this and the console is coming up with an "unexpected indentifier" error

Comment: Ok I have found the syntax mistake (changed "top:" to  "top":) Still not working :/ thanks anyway mate. I will keep on trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a correct JavaScript for your case. You don't need that .js-container anymore, it is bound directly to the post divs:

```
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        $('div.hentry.works').each(function () {
            // get the size and position
            var width = $(this).find('img').width(),
                height = $(this).find('img').height(),
                top = Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * $(window).height() - height), 0)),
                left = Math.floor(Math.max((Math.random() * $(window).width() - width), 0));

            // place the element
            $(this).css({
                "display": "block",
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": top,
                "left": left,
                "width": width,
                "height": height
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This also works! Many thanks. I understand the position absolute gets rid of the natural position of the posts but please let me know if you have know a quick way to random the left/right position while keeping the posts in a similar vertical order. 
kindest regards

Comment: ```position: relative``` works more on an offset basis. Would that not work? You would then have to rework the ```top =``` and ```left =``` sections a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured it out. The problem was that I was posting the `<script>` on the header.php. All works if I post the script in the "archive-$post_type.php".
Like this:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?><div class="js-container">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.js-container a').each(function() { 
var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400); 
    var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
$(this).css({
"top": top, 
"left": left, 
"position":"absolute", 
"display":"inline-block"
}); 
});
</script>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```